# Trying to run Python 3.7 in ATOM 1.30 but getting EOFError

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

I am new to programming (and to Stack Overflow) and I have an issue when trying to run Python code in ATOM text editor. I was watching some videos on Youtube on how to set up ATOM to run Python code and all was required was to install this package "atom-runner 2.7.1". However, upon running this very simple code:

```
name= input('Hello')
print(name)
```

I encountered the following error:

> HelloTraceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\Atom\pythontut.py",
>   line 1, in 
>       name=input('Hello') EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Thank you, and I hope this is the right place and way to ask, I have looked for an answer but I think this issue relates to the new versions of either ATOM or Python and all the answers were outdated.

Edit: I'm running windows 10 and here is a screenshot of the code and error, along with the packages installed

[Code-Error-Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6L4g.png)

Edit: I have installed all the mentioned packages, and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is your os?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://discuss.atom.io/t/eof-error-solved/57317/2. "The problem here is that atom-runner doesn’t have support for receiving user input. The Python interpreter is giving an error because it’s not receiving any valid input. I think [script-runner](https://atom.io/packages/script-runner) might suit your needs better."

Comment: I'm running windows 10

Comment: Actually, you need to load the extension "script" and that enables you to run python scripts. There is also an extension mentioned in another comment called "script runner". I'm not familiar with that one. If you load the "script" extension it then shows up under the packages menu.  Script-runner probably works too.